# Jump discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:A \to R$ where $A \subset R$ .

We say that f has a jump discontinuity at a point $p \in A $ iff
$lim_{x \to p-}f(x) $  and $lim_{x \to p+}f(x) $ exists but have different values.

Let J = { x $\in A$ : f has a jump discontinuity at x }.

I was interested in seeing if $J \subset Z$ for any infinite sets J ( finite or infinite ).

Can we have a function that has infinitely many jump discontinuities at non-integers , that is, at elements of $R-Z$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose your function $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $0$. Now consider the function $g(x) = f(x+r)$, where $r$ is any rational number (or irrational). This shifts the graph of $f$ by $r$. Now you have a jump discontinuity at $r$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know of an example of a function that has infinitely many jump discontinuities at non-integers ?

Comment: I assume that I interpreted your question correctly? If you were asking if given some subset $J$ of the integers, there exists a function with jump discontinuities at each point in $J$, that's a different matter.

Comment: For *any* countable subset $J$ of $\mathbb R$ there is an increasing function with jump discontinuities precisely at the points of $J$.

Comment: Andres Caicedo, thanks a lot for the answer. Can we also conclude that there is not a function $f:A \to R$ which has uncountably many jump discontinuties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not? Consider $f(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to x. This has infinitely many discontinuities at integers. Now consider $g(x) =f(x-a)$ where $a \in (0,1)$.

I might like to add that the set of jump discontinuities can be at most countable.

Comment: Can we have that the set  of jump discontintities on finite inteval of $\mathbb{R}$ is finite?

Comment: Isn't that true here?

Comment: Your example staisfy this property.My question whether there is a function which has infinite jump discontinuities on a finite interval.This function DOES exist.

Comment: Well yes. Off the top of my head, consider $[0,1]$. Look at the function $f(x)$ that is 1 if $x \in [1/2^n, 1/2^{n-1}]$ for $n$ even and $0$ elsewhere. This has infinitely many discontinuities in a finite interval.